# DVD RW Disk Unusable after Quick Erase

Tags: media, dvd-burning

I have noticed this a few times that the DVD RW Disk (even if it's relatively new) becomes unusable after a quick erase operation. The quick erase operation is successfully completed but the same media  is subsequently not detected by the drive. The DVD just spins and spins for minutes after minutes but is not detected at all.

I have LG DVD Writer and it is able to detect and read several disks be it ROM or R or RW. I use either Nero or BurnAware Free app.

What causes this behavior & is there any preventive action?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you performing the quick erase?

Comment: BurnAware Free-->Erase Disk -->Erase Re writable disk, select drive and leave speed as Max

Comment: Is there any reason you are still using DVR-RW instead of USB stick?  I had tons of issues with all forms of optical RW and gave it up as a lost cause.

Comment: My Gigabyte 880GMUSB3 board has known issues with USB Booting. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. So I find DVD booting more reliable in this case. I generally use DVD RW as a temporary bootable media when I am just experimenting with some OS installation.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and have coastered 30 or 40 DVD-RWs.  Did you every find the problem?  One site which is helpful (I am using linux) is: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Optical_disc_drive#Erasing_CD-RW_and_DVD-RW